# Image getting Trimmed in Sending Base64 encoded Email

Tags: java, c#

i am using a java web service and c# client. I have embedded image in Base64/jpeg format.unfortunately the image(embedded in mail) received in Lotus Notes(email client) is getting trimmed.

Before i am using Alternateview( in c#) that was working fine and perfectly showing images.
But now i have modified code and used Base64/Jpg conversion in mail body.

```
        string base64String = null;
        var matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*([""']?[^'"">]+?['""])[^>]*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            string src = match.Groups[1].Value;
            src = src.Trim('\"');
            using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(src))
            {
                if (File.Exists(src))
                {
                    var ext = Path.GetExtension(src);
                    if (ext.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ext = ext.Substring(1);
                        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                            base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                            src = string.Format("'data:image/{0};base64,{1}'", ext, base64String);
                            html = html.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, src);
                            // return base64String;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

`

Kindly help.

PS:: Sorry for my bad english.!!

EDIT::

Adding test Mail Body( added  tag also)

[Test Mail](http://pasted.co/8eff27df)

Comment: It might be helpful to generate a short test email and include the raw text in your question.